# Scan QR Code is not working after downloading the app from the play store in android

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, barcode

Testqr.java

```
public class Testqr extends Activity {

private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testqr);

        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        qrScan.initiateScan();

}

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (result != null) {
           // managed onBackpressed
      }
     else {
                callScanQRCodeMethod(result.getContents());
            }


}


private void callScanQRCodeMethod(String result) {

    if (result != null) {
        JSONObject jo = XML.toJSONObject(result);
        String userID = jo.getString("UserID");
        String authPass = jo.getString("UserName");
    }

}
```

}

I've implemented the following library to `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

I am confused about what to do with?

Comment: When I run it from the android studio, it's working fine. But, it creates a problem after downloading from the play store.

Comment: Do you ask for Camera permission? You might have camera permission enabled on your test device. Please check it out.

Comment: Yes. I've asked for camera permission. Without it, I cannot even get success while doing from Android Studio.